# PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress plugin which is using $this in public static method which is throwing error in PHP version 7.4.20 But the same code is running fine in lower versions like 7.1.14.

When I looked for the solution, It was mentioned that we can not use $this in public static method. But my question is why it is running in the older version of php. Was it discontinued from a particular version. I need more information. I tried to search but could not gather much information.

Example of static method is

```
public static function add_test_shortcode_metabox( $post ) {

    add_meta_box(
            'test-shortcode-metabox',
            esc_html__( 'Shortcode', 'theme-extensions' ),
            array( $this, 'display_test_shortcode_metabox' ) ,
            'theme_test',
            'side',
            'low'
        );
    
    }
```

Comment: surely before PHP5 it should work, since there is not"object"

Comment: It is even working in php version 7.1.14.

Comment: _“But my question is why it is running in the older version of php.”_ - because PHP was more fault tolerant regarding this in earlier versions, which could lead to different kinds of problems/errors (it must substitute $this with something else then) - and to avoid any such ambiguous situations, it has become more strict about this.

Comment: they have probably done this for backward compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Before it would result in a E_DEPRECATED warning now it's a Fatal error.

The message that you can read on the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) talks about calling non-static methods statically changes @v8.

[Other Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

I could not find the same info specifically about the `$this` change for the type of error prior to v8.0 and after 7.1 but it's the same.